# Вывод данных из бд по категориям PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, model

Проблема возникла с выводом данных из базы данных mysql.
Есть два метода в `ClassModel` (`MVC`) .  Первый выводит все категории полностью второй по категориям. Не работает второй метод (`selectByName($parametr)`) . Подскажите ошыбку. Заранее спасибо.

Вот код

Модель

```
class ClassModel
{
    static public function selectAll()
    {


        $image = array();


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pageimage`";

        $result = DataBase::connectDB()->query($sql);

        $i = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $image[$i]["image"] = $row["image"];
            $image[$i]["keywords"] = $row["keywords"];
            $i++;
        }

        return $image;
    }

    static public function selectByName($parametr)
    {

        $parametr = is_string($parametr);

        if ($parametr) 
        {


         $prepare = DataBase::connectDB()->prepare("SELECT keywords FROM  pageimage WHERE keywords= ?");

         $prepare->bind_param("s" , $parametr);

         $prepare->execute();

         $prepare->bind_result($image);

         $prepare->fetch();

         return $image; 

        }

    }
}
```

Контроллр

```
class PageController
{   

    function __construct()
    { 
        $image = array();   
        $image = ClassModel::selectAll();
        require_once("view/index.php"); 

    }

    public function actionCategory($parametr = false)
    { 



          $parametr = ClassModel::selectByName($parametr);


    }

}
```

Вид

```
<div class="category-navigation">
        <?php foreach($image as $keywords){ ?>
    <a href="/freetemplate/<?php print "category/" .$keywords["keywords"]; ?>" class="cat"><?php print $keywords["keywords"]; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
</div>

 <div class="row category-item">
    <div class="category-wrapping">
        <?php foreach($image as $key){ ?>
                <div class="category-container">
            <img src="/template/images/<?php print $key["image"]; ?>">
               </div>          
         <?php } ?>
         <?php if($parametr){ ?>
                <div class="category-container">
            <img src="/template/images/<?php print $parametr; ?>">
                </div>    
         <?php } ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: У вас в методе `selectByName` класса `ClassModel` приходит `$parametr`, но строчкой ниже вы его переопределяете как булево значение. Вероятнее всего должно быть не так `$parametr = is_string($parametr);`, а так хотя бы вот так `$parametr = (string) $parametr;`

Comment: Тут где-то был каноничный ответ о том, как ловить ошибки в PHP и в частности отладка. Я думаю надо его найти и дать автору. Это будет полезнее

Comment: Нашёл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/Как-и-какими-средствами-находить-ошибки-в-php-коде - посмотрите особенно вот этот пункт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/199253 Это очень полезно, чтобы не гадать

Answer (score 0):

В строке `$parametr = is_string($parametr);` происходит переопределение переменной `$parametr`, которой присваивается булевое значение (так как ф-я `is_string()` возвращает значение типа `bool`). Это можно исправить так:

```
static public function selectByName($parametr)
{
    $is_string = is_string($parametr);

    if ($is_string) {
```

Или так:

```
static public function selectByName($parametr)
{
    if (is_string($parametr)) {
```

Если вы используете PHP 7+ можно явно указать тип параметра `$parametr`, а валидацию делать за пределами метода `selectByName`:

```
static public function selectByName(string $parametr)
{
    $prepare = DataBase::connectDB()->prepare("SELECT keywords FROM  pageimage WHERE keywords= ?");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Выше сказанное два варианта использовал  но  не помогло .

Comment: @RiveraTimeClub какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Никакую ошибку не выдает

Comment: @RiveraTimeClub Выведите после `$prepare->fetch();` переменную `$image` (`var_dump($image);exit;`)

Comment: Значение  `NULL`

Comment: @RiveraTimeClub, значит у вас нет записи в БД со значением 'keywords' равным `$parametr`. Проверьте значение переменной `$parametr`, также попробуйте выполнить запрос "SELECT keywords FROM  pageimage WHERE keywords LIKE ?", написав вначале `$parametr = '%'.$parametr.'%'` (Это если у вас есть какие-то непечатаемые символы или пробелы в БД)

Comment: Наконец  сработало .  Спасибо всем за поддержку и за советы.